# Eclipse Subversion: Exclude Directories

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm on windows, running Eclipse Indigo with Subersive for connecting to a **REMOTE** svn repo.

I have a project checked out into a local folder. There are some directories in the project that I want to exclude from the check-in check-out process.

How can I do this? (I do not have SVN installed on windows, and WILL NOT install it separately due to various reasons.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `svn:ignore` property to the list of files/directories that you want to ignore on the directory that contains them.

The easiest way to do it seems to be through the "Team" context menu: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/SVNaction/ignore_vc.php

Comment: Thanks you for the rare 'advice and bloat free, non-philosophical' answer. I'd just like to add that the option in the team context menu 'Add to svn:ignore' will remain disabled for items already checked in. So to exclude an already checked-in directory from future svn check-in check-outs, first delete it in eclipse, then commit to svn (which will delete it from svn current stte as well), and then add it back in eclipse (copy into project), and now the Add to svn:ignore option in the team context menu will be available.

Comment: This helped, although wondering how can we check on which items have been added to SVN:ignore? Thanks